# How can I disable generating tern port files in Spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I found this pull request [#3465](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/3465), it says cherry-picked in develop branch.

I try to switch to develop branch, it truly remove tern port files, but I also found that there is some key binding not work (like `SPC w c`) in develop branch.

So I want to use the master branch, but I can not find any ways to disable generating tern port files...

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you can solve this with git.

```
cd ~/.emacs.d/
git checkout master
git checkout -b my-branch
git cherry-pick 73031fd7f20c2b5c5fb55a067f0c1fddc387152c # commit from #3465
```

You should have those changes now.

To update, do this:

```
cd ~/.emacs.d/
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```